# how to know data memory & program memory usage?

Tags: memory, memory-management, microcontroller, cortex-m, code-composer

I would like to know how much data memory and how much program memory i've  used on my microcontroller (a cortex M4)?

I am using code composer studio from texas instruments.

Comment: Would it help to view the assembly output? https://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/code_composer_studio/f/81/t/68716

Comment: Look at the .map file generated by the linker.

Comment: @starblue 
used flash: 0x2124 ram: 0x95c

How can I interprete this correctly?

 - 0x2124 bytes of ram have been used for program memory
 - 0x95c bytes have been used for data memory?

Comment: No. You have to lean some basics like the difference between flash and RAM, and what the different memory areas are for (.text, .data, .bss, maybe some more exotic ones). E.g., while most of the flash will be code, typically some of it will also be used for initializing data in RAM.

Answer (score 0):

The linker command file (.cmd) tells you to which blocks of memory the different sections (.text, .ebss etc) are linked. Also the type (program or data) of the section is defined in the linker command file.

From the .map file you can then see how much memory is used from these blocks.